# Nothing happens after clicking a button

Tags: windows-phone-8

First of all , question title may be bit irrelevant. I don't know how to put a title for this little mess. 
I developed a simple windows phone 8 application few days earlier. Today I just added the necessary images to the project for submitting in app store. When I tried to build in release mode, compiler gave me an exception in `App.xaml.cs` file in this line :

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Then I commented out this line just to check & after that my application is running. After clicking on a button in home page, app has gone in idle mode & it doesn't navigate to the other page. Page Navigation Code :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Category.xaml?", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Can anybody please tell me what is happening here ?

Comment: `When I tried to build in release mode, compiler gave me an exception` Could you add the details of the exception? It might help

Comment: It's a `NullPointerException`